# Node.js Adonis: how to attrach multiple controllers to only one websocket channel?

Tags: model-view-controller, websocket, adonis.js

I have simple project, based on Node.js framework called "Adonis". I would like to create a simplier multiplayer game using this framework. I have created one websocket channel, that would send and receive data among players and server. Then I have attached new controller to this channel:

```
const Ws = use('Ws')
Ws.channel('channelName', 'channelNameController')
```

The problem is, that data sent by users are very diverse. Players can execute various actions. (For example, players  can attack another player, they can buy things from another players, they can make move on the playing board etc).

I would like to preserve only one socket channel open, to make connection simple. But then, I would need to handle all data from players in the only one controller.

Is it possible to attach multiple controllers to one websocket channel, using Adonis framework?

If it is not possible, I would need handle all possible player's actions in one method in controller:

(pseudocode)

```
onMessage(message) {
  switch message.type:
   case 'player-moved':
     // do something...
     break;
   case 'player-attack':
     // do something...
     break;
 //...
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short

I don't think you can attach multiple controllers to one web-socket channel.
However, what you want to do here seems to be doable like you did in your pseudo code, or rather by sending different events (which I would recommend).

#### Client

```
socket.emit('attack', {player: foo, force: bar})
...
...
socket.emit('buy', {player: foo, item: 25}
```

#### Server

```
onAttack(data){
  doSomethingWith(data);
}

onBuy(data){
  doSomethingElseWith(data);
}
```